# How to run parallel hadoop mapreduce jobs in java

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, mapreduce, jobs

I am trying to write program that will run parallel jobs but it doesn't work.. 
I am trying to do the following:

```
 Hadoop.mapreduce.Job job=new Job[length]
    For(int i=0;i<length;i++){
     job[i].submit();
    }

    For(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    job[i].wait();
    }
```

My question is What I am doing wrong and how is it possible to execute multiple jobs in parallel

Comment: first of the `for loop` is written in lower case.

Comment: I dont have syntax error. Its just my phone but thanks

Comment: You should try the Thread library of Java. You can find some good examples all over the Internet.

Comment: Does it make sense to run job with thread?Job class implement/extend thread class not?

Comment: as @Souin said, you need to look at multithreading if you are wanting to execute multiple jobs in parallel. There are a couple ways to do it, but the most common ways are extending the `Thread` class,or more commonly you can implement the `Runnable` interface

Comment: First of all, what's a "Job" in your case? Because I don't know if it's a library, and if not, you should write it in lower case.

Comment: Its libary of hadoop mapreduce

Comment: Can you provide more details about the behavior you're seeing?  Are you using `waitForCompletion()`? (Critically, you should not be using `java.lang.Object.wait()`.)

Comment: If I will use waitForCompletion then the jobs will not run in parallel. @Suriname0

Comment: I guess , even though your code has some thread logic to invoke the jobs, they get queued and scheduled whcih can be tracked using job tracker

Comment: @MosheCh , What I am getting at is that you are misusing the [`wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait())function, which is why your code will not work.  Reading the javadoc for `Job` will clear things up.